# Black Ops: preferred way of dealing with cheaters

Tags: steam, call-of-duty-black-ops, cheats

Unfortunately Black Ops doesn't use PunkBuster, and VAC doesn't seem to be enough. So what is the preferred way to deal with players that are beyond any reasonable doubt cheaters (eg. you can clearly see in the kill cam, that they are using aimbot).

I've tried to find some information on the Steam, but it seems they assume that VAC will detect the cheat automatically, and I don't see a clear path to actually report cheater that wasn't detected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've reviewed the game(s) in the theater, click on the "Friends" button in the lower right on the main menu screen (multiplayer main menu). You'll see a tab for recently seen players. Find the player, click on them and click the button to view their player card. On there should be a button to report them.

I'm not near a machine with the game on it, so my instructions above might not be perfect, but hopefully they are close enough to get you there.

Also, keep in mind that some players out there are just sickly good. I've often been convinced that someone was a cheater then in theater realized that they were missing a lot of shots too. Or as a ghost I've been followed through a wall only to see in the theater that they were constantly careful when going around corners (not something that a wall hacker would be concerned with) and just happened to have an SR-whatever in the air when they killed me or saw a small piece of me running behind cover.

Comment: No, it wasn't a case of sickly good player, it was very clearly an aimbot. When human player aims gun at his target you can see that, but in this case you could see that he's not aiming, he's switching targets.

Comment: You certainly know better than me, since I wasn't in the games and can't see the video. I just wanted to throw that warning out there. Did the steps above work for you?

Comment: Yes, actually it did work. It's also possible to do that from the pause menu (i.e. pressing `Esc` while still on the server).

Answer (score 2):

From what I have heard, VAC bans are not immediate but can take anything from a few days to a month. I imagine that because bans are unappealable and permanent that they are reviewed before being out into effect to ensure that the ban is warranted.

My only suggestion would be to not play with these people. Find a server that is free of these people or play with friends instead of Internet folk.