# Kill cam shows player not being affected by concussion grenade; is this a perk or a hack?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops, cheats

While playing Call of Duty Black Ops (original PC version) there was a very high scoring player that appeared to be unaffected by my concussion grenades. I would throw a concussion grenade right in front of him but then he'd kill me instantly after. The playback on the kill cam shows he was completely unaffected the grenade. No slowing down, no disorientation, no ringing on the ears; it was like there was nothing done to him at all.

I know the Flack Jacket perk will make you stronger against claymores and other explosives, but I don't think it blocks the effects of concussion grenades.

I do not believe lag was the issue as the playback showed the grenade exploding right in-front of the player, which is alway what I saw when I threw it. My ping on that server is always in the low 20s - 30s and the other player never appeared to lag when I saw him or her.

**Is there a perk that blocks concussion grenades or was this player likely invoking some kind of cheat or hack?**

To address n_palum's comment, I'm not complaining about "losing" as he/she suggested. I run my own CoD server and would like to know how to identify hackers and cheaters. "Is there a perk that blocks concussion grenades or was this player likely invoking some kind of cheat or hack?" is a perfectly valid question and I believe it adds value to this site.

Comment: If you are going to down-vote my question, would you mind telling me what I need to change?

Comment: If you truly believe they were unaffected by your grenade, it sounds like a cheat or hack to me.  Considering this is PC and an older COD title, I can easily see this happening.

Comment: Take into consideration lag.

Comment: One more option: bug. Say, the server lost the packets about the grenade, or failed to send the reaction to it before the target shot. I don't know about COD but e.g. in World of Tanks, a long-known glitch is 'ghost shells', where your shot goes right through the enemy tank without affecting it in any way. You can't trigger it intentionally, and it happens to everyone regardless of configuration and connection. It just happens occasionally and there's nothing to do about it but to wait for Wargaming to fix the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Perk? Probably.
- Bug? Unlikely.
- Lag? Maybe.
- Cheat? Unlikely.

If you want to know the perk it is *[Tactical Mask](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Tactical_Mask) Pro*, which reduces the effect of flash and concussion grenades by 90%.

The killcam on the other hand is on your end, so you probably won't notice a cheating player just by watching grenades go off. There are [other things](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12534/how-do-i-determine-if-someone-is-cheating-in-call-of-duty-black-ops) you should look for. It is more common (but still pretty rare depending on your connection) to miss grenade effects in killcams because of lags. While you'd miss the effect in the killcam the other guy would still get hit by your grenade (if it was good/close enough).